# DIV moved with position: relative create gap between that div and next one

Tags: css

I have 2 `div`'s, one after the other. When i move first div with `postion: relative` and `top: -60px` it creates gap between them.

Here is example: https://codepen.io/dusannis/pen/oNgBpoK

As you can see there is gap between red and yellow div. Is there some css property that I can add to parent div that can remove this gap, or something simillar?

This is HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div-1">
      <p>something here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="div-2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is CSS:

```
body {
  background: blue;
  padding: 60px
}
.div-1 {
  padding: 60px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  background: red;
}
.div-2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for your response. The negative margin did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative margin instead of relative positioning.

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  padding: 60px
}

.div-1 {
  padding: 60px;
  /* position: relative; --> not required */
  margin-top: -50px;
  /* change this */
  background: red;
}

.div-2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div-1">
    <p>something here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div-2"></div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IuLfJ) of the effects of various methods of "moving" elements:

"Relative Position vs Margin vs Transform".

Answer (score -1):

You can try add same top/position to the second div:

```
.div-1 {
  padding: 60px;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  background: red;
}

.div-2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Alternatively you can add internal div and use padding for that one, then get rid of padding for the parent and the body (or adjust to the real value if you want it):

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div-1">
      <div class="div-1-inside">
         something here
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div-2"></div>
  </div>
</body>

body {
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
.div-1 {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.div-1-inside {
  padding: 60px;
  background: red;
}
.div-2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```